# Using both TMRpcm and VirtualWire libs with ATmega328, despite the conflict on TIMER1

Tags: timers, sd-card, virtualwire, tmrpcm

I wanted to use both [TMRpcm](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm) and [VirtualWire](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire/) with ATmega328 in an Arduino-like board I'm making, but both libraries use TIMER1. I wanted to use each lib for the following purposes:

- TMRpcm: play a WAV sound from an SD Card;
- VirtualWire: to receive commands from an RF remote control.

[TMRpcm Advanced Features Wiki](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki/Advanced-Features) has a section on [how to use TIMER2 instead](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki/Advanced-Features#timer2-usage), but I couldn't get it to work. They also say:

> Notes:
>
> 1. This is usually not the best solution.

So, before I spend any more time on this, I would like to hear what you guys have to say.

So, my question is: **is there a workaround to solve this conflict on the use of TIMER1, so I can use both libs in my project?**

If not, **what other alternatives do I have?**

My circuits for reading the SD card and driving the speaker are similar to the schematic in this Instructable: [Playing Wave file using Arduino](http://www.instructables.com/id/Playing-Wave-file-using-arduino/). And I'm using one of those
[433MHz Receiver modules](http://www.soldafria.com.br/datasheet/RWS-375-6(433_92mhz).pdf) for the RF part (standard, working circuit).

Both features, the RF receiver and SD card WAV playing, work correctly, when run separately (with separate sketches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around the issue by building a board with two ATmegas in it. One MCU handles the sound while the other handles the RF receiver, each using its own TIMER1, both communicating via I2C.

It's kind of a low tech dual core controller board. Not the most efficient solution, but it worked great for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could edit the VirtualWire.cpp source to use Timer2 instead of Timer1. For VirtualWire 1.18 the relevant section starts on line 512 with `#else // ARDUINO`.

On line 515 change `(uint16_t)-1` to `(uint8_t)-1` since Timer2 is only 8 bit. Then change all the TCCR1A, TCCR1B, OCR1A, TIMSK1 and OCIE1A to their Timer2 equivalent (hint: swap the 1's for 2's). Line 533 should be the last. On line 778 you also need to make a change to use TIMER2_COMPA_vect for VW_TIMER_VECTOR.

I hope that it helps.

Comment: For good measure also change OCIE1A to OCIE2A, and WGM12 to WGM22, though they have the same value so it will work without.

Comment: Gave it a try but couldn't make VW work with TIMER2. Instead, I'll try Manchester encoding lib a go...

Comment: Got the Manchester libs working, but also got a lot more dropouts with it, so I couldn't even get to make it work with TMRpcm.

Answer (score 1):

the virtual wire library has been obsoleted, and you should now use the [RadioHead](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/) library. In this RadioHead Library, you can edit the RH_ASK.cpp file, and uncomment the #define RH_ASK_ARDUINO_USE_TIMER2 near the top.